# Grails: Groovy error reported on tomcat plugin after creating a new project

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am using SpringSource Tool Suite

Version: 2.3.3.CI-R5608-B54
Build Id: 201008210801

with Java 1.6.0.u21 & Grails 1.3.5

I created a new grails plugin project and after the process was completed, STS reported problem as below. I had this problem before when creating grails project but usually got fixed if I do grails clean or project clean. But this time this problem is not getting fixed!

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type Groovy:The class java.lang.Class refers to the class java.lang.Class and uses 1 parameters, but the referred class takes no parameters TomcatServer.groovy /SampleGrails/tomcat-1.3.5-src-groovy/org/grails/tomcat line 439    Java Problem
```

What can be done to fix this problem?

Thank You.
Jay Chandran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce this in STS 2.5.0M3 so perhaps it's an issue that's already been fixed. You can install 2.5 from http://www.springsource.com/products/springsource-google-download. It's technically a milestone release but very stable and has a lot more features (esp Groovy and Grails) - I haven't had any issues using it.

You might also try the mailing list at eclipse-plugin-user@groovy.codehaus.org